# Python: Get Vector 3 direction from a Vector 3 rotation, eg: `0 0 45` = '0.5 0.5 0'

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, vector, rotation

I'm working on a Python program where I define my own vector 3D type. At least the way I imagined it, vectors can store both a position and rotation... if implementing quaternion rotations with 4 values is better I can attempt a `vec4` but I strongly prefer avoiding those since I understand them even less and they're much more cumbersome. Note that this is a general description of my `vec3` class, it can store either a position or rotation and objects can use an instance for each one (eg: `self.pos = vec3(4, 16, 0)` and `self.rot = vec3(0, 90, 180)`). What I have so far seems to work as intended and should need no further changes:

```
class vec3:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, z: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    def rot(self, other)
        self.x = (self.x + other.x) % 360
        self.y = (self.y + other.y) % 360
        self.z = (self.z + other.z) % 360
    def dir(self):
        # This is where the magic I'm missing must happen
        return vec3(self.x / 360, self.y / 360, self.z / 360)

v = vec3(0, 90, 180)
# Result: 0 90 180
v.rot(vec3(-90, 45, 270))
# Result: 270 135 90
v.dir()
# Result: 0.75 0.375 0.25
# Correct range but doesn't represent direction
```

The issue I'm struggling with is how to get the real direction the vector is pointing toward, meaning the virtual arrow jutting out from the origin and pointing toward where this vector is looking: X is right, Y is forward, Z is up. Its rotation alone doesn't represent it: A rotation of `0 0 0` should be a direction of `0 1 0`, one of `0 0 45` (45* to the right) should probably translate as `0.5 0.5 0` (half of the forward direction is ceded to the right direction), if we add another 45* to look all the way to the right we have `0 0 90` which would point toward `1 0 0`. I don't mind if the directions are mixed up from how I'm imagining them, as long as this is done correctly and all possible combinations are predictable. What is the simplest conversion algorithm possible I can use in my `dir` function?

Comment: quaternions are only cumbersome _because_ you don't understand them. There's tons of great explainers on using quaternions for game programming out there. That said, I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say a Vec3 can store a position and a rotation: a 3D position is three values, so now your Vec3 is full. Where is it supposed to store the rotational component? You'd need a Vec6 to simultaneously store 3D position with rotation in three planes.

Comment: The position is a separate vector, edited to clarify: I just offered a description of my general `vec3` class, it can then be used by other classes to store a `self.pos = vec3()` and `self.rot = vec3()` separately. When used to store rotation, the `rot` function works in changing the rotation values accordingly. My only problem is I don't know how to translate this rotation to a direction so the code knows where it's pointing toward.

Comment: you're very close to the solution in your own description text already: (0,0,45) with 45 for Z is a 45 degree rotation of the XY plane. So convert that to radians, which gives (0,0,pi/4), and this rotation of XY will have an  x rotation of cos(pi/4), and a y rotation of sin(pi/4), i.e. (0.7071, 0.7071, 0). While technically (0.5, 0.5, 0) also describes a "45 degree rotation", that's not a unit vector, and presumably all your rotations are implied to be unit vectors.

Comment: Those bizarre values are why I didn't go with them: `math.sin` and `math.cos` produce strange values like `0.8414709848078965` or `1.2246467991473532e-16` which won't transform correctly. Angles `0 90 180 270 360` are meant to translate to directions `-1 0 +1 0 -1`, values may be offset and - / + flipped as that's a matter of preference on where the default direction should point to. See what I answered below, I managed to get a result which at least works as desired though it can probably be written better.

Comment: Those aren't "bizarre values". Those are literally the numbers you get when you draw this out on a piece of paper. In order to stay on the unit sphere, x² + y² + z² has to stay 1, which is a fundamental property of the trigonometric functions. You don't _want_ (0.5, 0.5, 0) for a 45 degree turn, you want (0.7071, 0.7071, 0) because that vector has unit length, making _everything you do with it_ easier. `1.2246467991473532e-16` is a valid problem though: welcome to IEEE floating points, that's how they work. You'll have to round numbers to less-than-precision decimal places.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm trying out your advice, I see why 0.5 / 0.5 isn't ideal as it behaves like a square. But I need a 0* - 360* range: I tried `for i in (0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360): print(math.sin(math.radians(i)))` which is for the most part accurate, yet for 360* I get a value of `-2.4492935982947064e-16` which is clearly wrong as it should be returning back to `0` instead, if I use cos it's even worse as 90 produces `6.123233995736766e-17`. Any advice on how I should tweak that to get a proper virtual circle? Can I just bind it to `-1 - +1` range without losing accuracy?

Comment: To be clear: I've read about the precision error limitation in computing such numbers, got a rough idea of why this is happening. It's not the accuracy that bothers me: If instead of a perfect `0` I got something like `0.000001` I wouldn't mind. The problem is I get floating values that start with `2` or even `6`, using them would break everything. I could just limit between `-1` and `+1` but then any value that occurs in between would be floored / ceiled and I'm essentially losing data and creating stops. Should I just divide everything by the largest such number that can occur?

Comment: Correcting myself: Those odd values are in fact within range, they only appear to be 2 or 6 due to a scientific notation I wasn't familiar with. I plugged them into my formula and got the desired results immediately! Thanks for the help, if you posted it as an answer I'd happily mark it as the solution.

Comment: Yeah, the part that matters is the number after the `e`, which tells you how many zeroes there actually are, and whether the number is huge, or truly tiny. `2e5` is a 2 "five places in front of the decimal point", i.e. `200000`, whereas `2e-16` is a 2 "16 places past the decimal point", i.e. it's actually `0.0000000000000002`. I've also written an answer based on my comments for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a rotation vector where each value says how much to rotate around that axis, which really means "how much to rotate the plane spanned by the other two dimensions by", so that a rotation vector `(0,0,45)` represents a 45 degree rotation about the **Z** axis, i.e. a rotating of the **XY** plane by an eighth of a turn.

We can do this with a quick conversion from degrees to radians (so `(0,0,45)` becomes `(0,0,pi/4)`) so that we can trivially compute what the rotations for **X** and **Y** should be using basic trigonometry:

```
degreeVec3 = (0,0,45)
rotation = new Vec3()
angle = radians(degreeVec3.z)
rotation.x = cos(angle)
rotation.y = sin(angle)
```

So the original `(0,0,45)` becomes `(0.7071, 0.7071, 0)`, a quarter turn `(0,0,90)` becomes `(0,1,0)`, `(0,0,135)` becomes `(-0.7071, 0.7071, 0)`, etc.

The benefit of this approach is that by doing things this way, we are assured that our resulting rotation vector is always a unit vector, which makes doing any sort of additional work much easier than if we just tried to come up with some random set of values that effect the same rotation. For example, while any `(s, s, 0)` vector represents a 45 degree rotation in the **XY** plane, only s=0.7071 will give us a unit vector, and trig functions help ensure we do.

Answer (score 0):

Originally posted yesterday, updating with two-directional solution. I managed to produce a test that does what I want math wise... no roll but you can look left / right as well as up / down, starting to see why quatenions are used since a 4th value would be needed to support that. I don't like how it's written and a cleaner way to achieve the same result would be appreciated but for now it's good enough.

Note that I tried `math.sine` / `math.cos` which seemed ideal, but no matter what I did I couldn't get the result to have the proper range, eg: `0* == +1, 90* == 0, 180* == -1, 270* == 0, 360* == +1` like I managed to get below. For example `math.sin(1) == 0.8414709848078965` or `math.sin(math.pi) == 1.2246467991473532e-16`... I don't fully understand why those bizarre values occur but they are definitely useless.

```
import math

angle_x = 90
for angle_z in (0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360):
    deg_x = (180 + angle_z) % 360
    deg_y = angle_x % 360
    deg_z = (90 + angle_z) % 360
    dir_x = 1 - abs(1 - math.radians(deg_x / math.pi)) * 2
    dir_y = 1 - abs(1 - math.radians(deg_y / math.pi)) * 2
    dir_z = 1 - abs(1 - math.radians(deg_z / math.pi)) * 2
    print("x: " + str(dir_x) + " y: " + str(dir_y) + " z: " + str(dir_z))
```

This produces the desired result:

```
x: 1.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.0
x: 0.5 y: 0.0 z: 0.5
x: 0.0 y: 0.0 z: 1.0
x: -0.5 y: 0.0 z: 0.5
x: -1.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.0
x: -0.5 y: 0.0 z: -0.5
x: 0.0 y: 0.0 z: -1.0
x: 0.5 y: 0.0 z: -0.5
x: 1.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.0
```